# PHP replace characters in an array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have data like this in my array first_name, last_name,....

I am looking for an array to replace the _ with a space..is this possible?

I took alook at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php but I am not sure if this is what I want.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  $array[$key]=str_replace("_"," ",$value);
}
```

That should do it, right?

Answer (score 18):

Just with `str_replace`, it takes either strings or arrays in all arguments that matter:

```
var_dump(str_replace('_',' ',array('foo_bar','lorem_ipsum')));


array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "foo bar"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "lorem ipsum"
}
```